# sql server xml.value skeleton dynamic cases

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005.I want to enquiry xml records to row by rows.
So that I was used the below codes. There is three records. When I excuted like that, I can see the one records only.

`DECLARE @Xml XML`

```
DECLARE @Emp TABLE(ps NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,inv NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL)


INSERT INTO @Emp(ps,inv)

SELECT  @Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/PSTATION)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),

@Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/INVNUMBER)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

 SELECT * FROM @Emp
```

So that, I use next two SQL Statements the above SQL.
I want to use dynamic for index.Can I use? Please advise.

```
@Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/PSTATION)[2]/[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

INSERT INTO @Emp(ps,inv)

SELECT  @Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/PSTATION)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),

@Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/INVNUMBER)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

INSERT INTO @Emp(ps,inv)

SELECT  @Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/PSTATION)[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),

@Xml.value('(/NewDataSet/POSDetails/INVNUMBER)[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nodes()` to shred the XML into rows on `POSDetails` element level, then use `value()` to extract the inner text of `PSTATION` and `INVNUMBER` as NVARCHAR data, something like this :

```
INSERT INTO @Emp(ps,inv)
SELECT 
    P.value('(PSTATION)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    P.value('(INVNUMBER)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @Xml.nodes('/NewDataSet/POSDetails') AS T(P)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it